# How to display AlertDialog in a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-alertdialog, android-context

I want to display an alert dialog in my app. I am using fragments. I tried the below code to do this:

```
 AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .create();
    ad.setCancelable(false);
    ad.setTitle(title);
    ad.setMessage(message);
    ad.setButton(context.getString(R.string.ok_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
ad.show();
```

but it was crashing and the error in logcat was:

> 04-18 15:23:01.770: E/AndroidRuntime(9424): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

From internet I came to know that the crash is due to context issue. I had given context as

```
context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

I don't know what is the problem with this. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Replace `context` with `getActivity()`.

The `ApplicationContext` should not be used for tasks such as creating Dialogs. As you are in a fragment you can instead get the Activity-Context simply by calling the Fragments `getActivity()` method.

Comment: What should do if getActivity() is null?

Comment: @SujithPt When `getActivity()` returns null, it means that the fragment is not attached to the activity and you should not show any dialogs.

Comment: @SujithThankachan you can wait till the getActivity() is not null. I havenot tried it out though.

Comment: requireActivity() new method was added in [february 2018](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#27-1-0) which in case it return null it throws an exception. If you are sure this method will not return null because you are using between onAttach and onDetach you can use it to get ride ot the warning that getActivity() might return null.

Answer (score 16):

**More Information about this question (AlertDialog in a fragment, managed inside an event):**

If you call AlertDialog within an event like onClick(View v) or onLongClick(View v) you can use

```
public boolean onClick(View v) {
    ...
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try to use DialogFragment, DialogFragment is better when you use Fragments

Comment: can you please post a sample code for that?this is the first time i am hearing about DialogFragment

Comment: link is dead @FUBUs

Comment: @andro-girl https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues whereby I was trying to create an AlertDialog from a Fragment. A NullPointerException arose from it. Initially I did as follows:

```java
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
```

The `NullPointerException` occurred specifically when calling `alertDialog.show()` later on in the code.
But after searching the documentation for `AlertDialog.Builder()`, there seemed to be another way to initialize it [[AlertDialog.Builder Doc]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html), which is to include a theme/resId as shown below:

```java
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert).create();
```

This resolved the `NullPointerException` at hand. Hope this helps you as well!

Answer (score 1):

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

Comment: duplicate answer to the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I used it in an adapter inside a listView, therefore I couldn't use `getActivity()`. In order to make it work I used `getActivity()` for the context in the instantiation of the adapter in the fragment:

```
this.adapter = new myAdapter(getActivity(), factory);
```

Later in the other class (the adapter's class) I was able to use `getContext()`and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
                       AlertDialog alert= null;
                        AlertDialog.Builder build= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        build.setTitle("title");
                        build.setItems(stringarrayname, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

                            }
                        });
                        build.create().show();
```

Comment: i got the alert dialog by using this code in fragments

Comment: this code is wrong, you should use alert= build.create();
alert.show();

Answer (score -1):

You can try this or use DialogFragment

```
private void showAlert(final int position) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                .setTitle("Delete entry")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      //  deleteSuggestions(position);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to replace by `getActivity()`

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),R.style.MaDialog);
```